# can tf alone train a 20 million-plus rows dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I wanna train a model in tf using a dataset of more than 20 million rows. Are there any limitations/errors that may happen when performing this? Are there any methods/techniques I could try to effectively perform this?. The problem is simple classification one but I've never trained with such a large dataset. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow can handle *petabytes* of information passed across tens of thousands of GPUs - the question is, does *your* code manage resources properly, and can *your* hardware handle it? This is called [distributed training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training). The topic is very broad, but you can get started with [setting up a GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) - that includes installing CUDA & cuDNN. You can also refer to input data pipeline [optimization](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance).

I suggest handling all your installs via [Anaconda 3](https://anaconda.org/), as it handles package compatibility - here's a [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc) or [two](https://medium.com/@ab9.bhatia/set-up-gpu-accelerated-tensorflow-keras-on-windows-10-with-anaconda-e71bfa9506d1) to get started.

Lastly, your main hardware constraints are RAM and GPU memory; former for the maximum array size a model can process (e.g. 8GB), and latter for maximum model size the GPU can fit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using a system with 8gb and no GPU, hence my concern. I was thinking of trying an implementation using a combination of spark and tf if necessary(in case tf doesn't work).

Comment: @alankoshy Your training will be at least 10x as slow for mid-sized+ datasets - I'd highly recommend at least a GTX1060. Alternatively, [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/) offers a free GPU faster than GTX1070 and with 12GB GPU memory and 12GB RAM, for free. There's a 12-hr limit before a disconnection, but isn't a problem with model checkpoints.

Comment: I'll consider that option. btw does using estimators make sense in my case?

Comment: @alankoshy It is an option, but I'd recommend [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) instead. Estimators involve lots of low-level coding.